# Tell ssh to try all key files in ~/.ssh/

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I have multiple keys in my ~/.ssh/ directory, each with a separate project name, for projects that have multiple servers each.  id_rsa_project1, id_rsa_project2

However, ssh won't search for them.  If I run `ssh -v user@projectserver` I get output like the following:

```
...
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@projectserver password:
```

This appears to be by design, as the `ssh_config` manpage says that, by default, the Identities searched for are **~/.ssh/id_dsa**, **~/.ssh/id_ecdsa**,
**~/.ssh/id_ed25519** and **~/.ssh/id_rsa**.

Of course, I can:

- add the `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_project1` switch to the command line each time, or
- add **IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_project1** to a specification against the server in *~/.ssh/config*, or
- add **IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_project1** to */etc/ssh/ssh_config* for each project.

...but all these seem too cumbersome for the regularity with which we change keys and key files.

I did try to add **IdentityFile ~/.ssh/*** to */etc/ssh/ssh_config* but it appears to take it as a literal * rather than a wildcard.

**How can I tell ssh to read and try *all* key files in ~/.ssh/ ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to add them to `ssh-agent`:

Start agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Add all keys in `~/.ssh`:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_*
```

But note that it is not ideal way, since all the keys are tried on all the servers where you want are connecting. Proper configuration in `~/.ssh/config` is advised solution.

Comment: Do I have to rerun this every time I change the keys in ~/.ssh/ ?

Comment: If you change the keys often, you are doing something wrong. How often do you change the keys from our car?

Comment: Every time I get a new hire car, actually. :-p

Comment: You really should use the .ssh/config method. Trying them all can lead to the ssh server dumping you for too many attempts, and you never know what hardware you may accidentally connect to.